# How to create breadcrumbs based on menu structure

Tags: menu, 3.5.1, breadcrumbs

Breadcrumbs grabs the breadcrumb trail based on the content. This causes problems when a site has internal links being created via the editor to other articles that do not have menu items.

eg: Home / Menu Item Level 1 / Menu Item Level 2 / Menu Item Level 3 / Category / Sub Category / Article

What I need is a breadcrumb that matches the menu path of the closest menu item. So if you're looking at things in the 3rd tier, you see a menu path back to the 1st tier, but only of the current menu item.

eg: Menu Item Level 1 / Menu Item Level 2 / Menu Item Level 3

I have no idea how to accomplish this. I don't think I can do it with the breadcrumb module at all, I could create custom menus for every single tier but there's a lot of unknowns there, since most of these articles don't even have menu items. (client put their site together this way, I'm just trying to make it work best I can).

So to clarify: how do I make a breadcrumb path that follows the menu structure, not the article / category structure?

**I didn't actually have time to wait on this answer, so I did go with the custom menu modules, one for each tier, assigned for each menu. It's working pretty well, so I won't be using the alternative, but if someone does know how to make this happen, I can't be the only one who was wondering!

Comment: Can you give more detail as to the URL, menu, and category structure of the pages in question?

Comment: I'm not sure it matters - I basically just want to create a breadcrumb from menu items instead of the content.

Comment: It does matter. Breadcrumbs follow those 3 items. The same article can be read in different ways with different breadcrumbs output each time...
Example of same article with different URL and breadcrumbs: https://www.steelmarketupdate.com/blog/9525-empire-state-survey-indicates-weaker-manufacturing-activity-in-august **OR** https://www.steelmarketupdate.com/news/9525-empire-state-survey-indicates-weaker-manufacturing-activity-in-august

Comment: That's my problem. I want it to use the MENU ITEMS and never the categories or the articles. Whether it's just a single article, a top level category, or a 5th level sub category, or a JEvents menu item, I want to use the menu item path instead of the content path for the breadcrumbs.

Comment: If menu items is your primary determining factor for the breadcrumbs content, then menu items must be setup for ALL elements in your breadcrumbs.

Comment: Yeah thanks, that's why I added: "What I need is a breadcrumb that matches the menu path of the closest menu item." If you don't think it's possible, then just say that. I already above mentioned I had to come up with a custom fix.

Answer (score 0):

> I basically just want to create a breadcrumb from menu items instead of the content.

I recently had the same problem. After a lot of work, I concluded that the Joomla breadcrumbs module is buggy. The solution for me was to use the Joomla extensions called "Breadcrumbs Advanced".

Comment: Awesome! Glad you found a solution that works for you.

Comment: It's not buggy, it just doesn't work the way you want it to. It's intended to be simplistic, to leave room for extension developers to create more elaborate solutions. It's also not very forgiving for deviations from the way it wants to work. But again, that's not buggy, just limited.